# Plotting Multiple Regression Parameters (ggplot in R Studio)

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, replication, economics

** Update: Solution Found, See Bottom For Answer **

Hello I am trying to replicate an economics paper. I have the following model that needs to be graphed:

## Economics Paper Mathematical Model/Results ----------

Variables: LNEARN, EDUC, EXP, ysm, and the only binary variable LANG (see below)
LNEARN ~ 0.049EDUC + 0.023EXP - 0.037 (EXP^2/100) + 0.028 ysm - 0.041(ysm^2/100) + LANG + 5.056

## Reported Means of Variables in Economics Paper -----------

If it is important for fixing some of my variables, here are the paper's reported means of the variables that aren't being varied along x and y in my ggplot:

mean reported EXP: 22.76
mean reported ysm: 15.43

## The graphical output of the code is attached in the link below

[Current Output: Data-Generated Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcRYo.png)

```
# Current Code (Runs Properly) -----------------
# Creates model with data
# Recall only LANG takes on binary 0 and 1!
m_i <- lm(LNEARN ~ EDUC + EXP + I(EXP^2/100) + ysm + I(ysm^2/100) + as.factor(LANG), df_clean)

  ggplot(df_clean, aes(x = EDUC, y = LNEARN, color = LANG, size = ysm)) +
# Graphs data points
geom_point() +
# Data-generated regression
geom_smooth() +
# Cosmetic
xlab("Years of Formal Education") +
ylab("Log of Earnings") +
ggtitle("Education's Potential Impact On Immigrant Earnings") +
labs(subtitle = "1990 US Census Data", color = "Language", size = "Education") +
theme_pander()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do. If you already have the model parameters and just want to graph it, why not just make a function with those parameters and use that to make a dataframe? I don't see why you need to fit again using the `lm` function.

Comment: I haven't learned how to do functions formally. I tried to teach myself, but the ones I've made keep coming up with errors. How would you write it out?

Comment: There is a `geom_function`. Why don't you run some examples with it using material on its halp page and tutorial and  You would probably assume that the values for all variables other than EDUC were at their means. Then you should be in a position to draw the estimated regression line on those coordinates.

Comment: the `ggeffects` package might be helpful.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, can you please post the solution as an answer rather than editing your question to include the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
# The problem was that my function in educ_equation_lang0 and educ_equation_lang1 didn't include * in the right places, so it was calling numbers I wanted to multiply as objects
# Useful troubleshooting was to check class(educ_equation_lang0) if it was read as a function
# Then I tried educ_equation_lang0(3) to see if the function could give an output (which it couldn't, and that's how I knew!)

m_i <- lm(LNEARN ~ EDUC + EXP + I(EXP^2/100) + ysm + I(ysm^2) + as.factor(LANG), df_clean)

educ_equation_lang0 <- function(x){0.049*x + 0.023*22.76 - 0.037*(22.76^2/100) + 0.028*15.43 - 0.041*(15.43^2/100) + 5.056}
educ_equation_lang1 <- function(x) {0.049*x + 0.023*22.76 - 0.037*(22.76^2/100) + 0.028*15.43 - 0.041*(15.43^2/100) + 1 + 5.056}

ggplot(df_clean, aes(x = EDUC, y = LNEARN, color = LANG, size = EXP)) +
    xlab("Years of Formal Education") +
    ylab("Log of Earnings") +
    ggtitle("Education's Potential Impact On Immigrant Earnings") +
    labs(subtitle = "1990 US Census Data", color = "Language \n (Speaks English 1 \n /Doesn't Speak 0)", size = "Education") +
    geom_point() +
    geom_function(fun = educ_equation_lang0, colour = "red") +
    geom_function(fun = educ_equation_lang1, colour = "lightblue") +
    geom_smooth() +
    theme_pander()
```

[Graph to Final Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gv4HI.png)